# How can i change the size of a point on a plot every timestep

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this project where i am trying to very simplistically simulate the growth of plants.
I am using matlplotlib to plot plants (points) onto a grid, and for example i have a variable called "weather". If weather is rainy, then i want the scatter plot point on the grid to increase in size and remain that way, but for every time step, if this weather condition is met, the size of the point should increase. Some example code of my attempt:

```
timestep = 10
l1 = []
for d in range(timestep):
l1.append(d)

def plot_plant_scatter(plants, limits):
xlist = []
ylist = []
s = 40
clist = []
for k in range(len(plants)):
    ylist.append(limits[0] - plants[k].getRow() - 1)
    xlist.append(plants[k].getCol())
    for d in range(timestep):
        if weathercond[d] == "Rain":
            s = s + 20
        else:
            s = s + 10
    clist.append(k)
plt.scatter(xlist, ylist, s, c=clist)
```

Where getRow and getCol are just things to find the x and y coords of the plots.

This def function will be placed inside a simulation loop so that every timestep it will replot the points.

This code above doesnt work as id like it too and i would like some guidance so that i can make it work.

Comment: Why exactly doesn't it work as you wish? Could you share some data to test? Maybe add a second variable as `rs = 0` and change its value to `20` if it is rainy and then on the scatter line you add the size parameter as `s = s + rs`.

Comment: Why don't you scatter the single points in the loop, each with the wished size? As it is now, with the current indentation, it just seems you will have scatter dots all of the same (enormous) size.